# Arduino | Everything on the X-axis works but not on the Y-axis

Tags: arduino

I want to make a simple memory game for the Arduino. But instead of buttons I want to use a joystick to select the blinking LEDs.

I am in the early stage of the project but my Y-axis won't read and I can't figure the problem out.

```
//Joystick
const int X_pin = A4;
const int Y_pin = A5;
int Joy_Waarde;
//leds
const int led_Rood = 13;
const int led_Groen = 12;
const int led_Blauw = 11;
const int led_Geel = 10;
//componenten
const int buzzer = 4;

int X_Value = 0;
int Y_Value = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode (led_Rood, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (led_Groen, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (led_Blauw, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (led_Geel, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  randomSeed(analogRead(A0));
  Serial.println("Het spel is begonnen!");
}

void loop() {
  X_Value = analogRead(X_pin);
  Y_Value = analogRead(Y_pin);
  if (X_Value == 1023) {
    digitalWrite(led_Groen, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led_Groen, LOW);
  }
  if (X_Value == 0) {
    digitalWrite(led_Blauw, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led_Blauw, LOW);
  }
  if (Y_Value == 1023) {
    digitalWrite(led_Geel, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led_Geel, LOW);
  }
  if (Y_Value == 0) {
    digitalWrite(led_Rood, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led_Rood, LOW);
  }
}
```

Hopefully you guys now something about it! Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know that it isn't read?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You said "my Y-axis won't read". How do you know?

Comment: My mistake, my Y-Axis does read. I used another code to check if i get results by using the serial monitor.

Comment: But in this code my leds won't turn on. I don't get why, its the same wiring as the other 2 leds that do work.

Comment: Are you sure it can read both extremes 0 and 1023?

Comment: Thank you gre_gor for you time!

Comment: I just found the problem, and it was indeed in my wiring. I set the leds horziontal now and they work perfectly fine! thank you

Answer (score 0):

It worked, It was something with the wiring!

Thank you!